# UIAppearance for UINavigationBar not working when used with custom view controller...?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I have a method which sets the appearance of UINavigationBar. FlightSearchViewController is subclassed from UIViewController but the nav bar is not updated as expected. If I write UIViewController in place of FlightSearchViewController every thing works fine.

```
private class func setupNavigationBarAppearance() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .Black
        UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.ixiRegularFontOfSize(17)]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Color.navBarThemeColor

        var navBarAppearanceControllers = [AnyObject.Type]()
        navBarAppearanceControllers.append(FlightSearchViewController.self)
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses(navBarAppearanceControllers)
        navBarAppearance.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        navBarAppearance.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        navBarAppearance.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
        navBarAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navBarAppearance.translucent = true
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.ixiRegularFontOfSize(17)]
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to change the color of navigation bar for a particular viewController. Right?

Comment: yes............. and other things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your navigation bar is not contained in `FlightSearchViewController`, rather it is a above it in view controller hierarchy. 'appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses' means `UINavigationBar` contained in your viewController will get updated. But it isn't the case since navigationBar in contained in UINavigationController.

If you try

`let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UIViewController.self])`, it will work. But, you will see the changes on every view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to replace:

```
    var navBarAppearanceControllers = [AnyObject.Type]()
    navBarAppearanceControllers.append(FlightSearchViewController.self)
    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses(navBarAppearanceControllers)
    navBarAppearance.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    navBarAppearance.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    navBarAppearance.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    navBarAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navBarAppearance.translucent = true
    navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.ixiRegularFontOfSize(17)]
```

With:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = true
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.italicSystemFontOfSize(17)]
```

Comment: The code in question already uses UINavigationBar.appearance(). `appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses` is used to override that for requisite views.